# graphql mutation response type

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

We have a lot of mutations in our service that all of those return the same type of response like there:

```
export default new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'MessageResponse',
  fields: () => ({
    message: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
  }),
});
```

My question is could I return this type for all of these mutations as a best practice or I have to create single type for each of those mutations?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you would want to have different types in this scenario is if you needed it implement a different `resolve` function for your message field. If that's not the case, then it's perfectly fine to use the same type.

Also, bear in mind that it's also possible to just return a scalar at root level. For instance, your Mutation type can look like this:

```
new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Mutation',
  fields: () => ({
    someMutation: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
  }),
})
```

This isn't always a good idea (for example, if you anticipate need to return additional information in the future). However, it's worth pointing out that it is possible.